# Server Request every second

Tags: django, performance, server, load

I have implemented a django web app which requires a get request from the server every second which I call through ajax without refreshing the page.
At a time only 8 people can be accessing the server at a time so that is 8 requests per second which go to the database and return selected objects.

It is to be deployed on a server with 128gb ram and 1.9 Tb hardisk.

Will the server crash?

Comment: I want to know what the every second request do. Is it execute a slow query? Maybe you should optimize your query in database. And did you deployed django on nginx or something else?

Comment: The query will be taking maximum of around 2000 , 200 character messages and display around 500 of them.
The stats are absolute maximum

I right now don't have knowledge about using what it is to be deployed , Although there is no constraint on that ,Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: So...is it running with Django’s built-in server?

Comment: actually it is not currently deployed , it is in testing phase
I asked around , we are gonna deploy most probably using nginx and on a local network

Answer (score 0):

No, the server won't crash with that features.

the server will crash if your database is not optimized, if you are not caching data.